# QueueBackgroundWorkItem vs. Task.Run for background task

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker

I'm new to background work (and generally in Task usage) and have a doubts about my implementation.

(Note: If you think it's too long, let me know by comment and I'll shorten it)

Assume a WCF service which returns currencys rates:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class RatesServiceSvc : IGetRatesService
```

- The `RatesServiceSvc` depends on `IRatesService`(singelton).
- `IRatesService` depens on `IRatesQueueDispatcher`.
  holds `ratesCache` dictionary. and in its constructor calls to `RunDispatcher(_ratesQueue, _dispatcherCancellationTokenSource);`

The internal implementation of the `IRatesService` is like this: The service instantiate a third party queue which gets from the network the current rates and pushes them as events to the queue (endlessly). In order to fetch the events I need to invoke the `IRatesQueueDispatcher.Run(...)` that runs backgroun loop:

The `IRatesService` implementation:

```
private void RunDispatcher(Queue queue, CancellationTokenSource dispatcherCancellationTokenSource)
    {
        Task<TaskCompletionCause> dispatcher = Task.Run(() => _queueDispatcher.Run(queue, dispatcherCancellationTokenSource.Token));
        dispatcher.ContinueWith((dispatcherTask) =>
        {
            HandleRunningTaskTermination(dispatcherTask.Result);
        });
    }
```

IRatesQueueDispatcher.Run() Imlementation:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && IsRatesQueueOk(eventsCount))
        {
            eventsCount = ratesQueueToDispatch.Dispatch();
            if (eventsCount < 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(_sleepTimeWhenReutersQueueEmpty);
            }
        }
```

The `queue.Dispach()` call, leads to invoke (in the same thread) to the implementation of `EventClient.ProcessEvent(event)` (which registered in the initialization phase). The data fetched from the events inserted to the `rateCache` (in this case it's a `ConcurrentDictionary`)

The application needs:

- The background loop will run endlessly.
- If background loop fails for some reason I need to know it immediately.
- If application has another issue I need to kill the background task.

The question:
Do my solution of running the backgroun work by `Task.Run(...).ContinueWith(...)` is Ok? I read in some palces about "Fire and Forget" Dangers ([here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks#the-problem-with-fire-and-forget) 
 and [here](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/)) also I know .NET 4.5.2 suggests the [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.7.2)

but I'm not sure if it's the appropriate solution for me. Because:

1. I need to know if the worker failed from its internal reason.
2. It seems to me that the main purpose of the `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is to promise the finish of the running task before `application_end`. For my needs There isn't meaning of running the background work when application ends, and also vice versa - If background failed there is no meaning of the application to run without it. For that reason I implemented the `HandleRunningTaskTermination()` to recycle the application by invoke `System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();`.

After all, I'm worried about my implemetation and I'm looking for a better solution. There is better??

Comment: I didn't read the question yet, but just from the subject - are you sure you want to run infinite task in WCF? I would definitely not do this, because WCF is not designed for this sort of tasks and you probably will bring many problems with it. Instead, you can run your background job as a separate daemon. It can be the same app \ windows service which hosts your WCF.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev The WCF service not used to run background work. It uses background work in order to populate the cache with currency data, which in turn will returened in the WCF `GetRate()` request. In telling this, it seems more reasonable?

Comment: I would create a dedicated service app to run the "endless" loop.  You can also implement your WCF service in it. If you need or want to have your WCF service hosted by IIS, then from your WCF service you can call the service app (again via WCF) to send commands and get results.  This will enable you to have a proper control over the life of your "endless" loop, restart it, if necessary, and be independent from IIS.

Comment: @Nick _I would create a dedicated service app to run the "endless" loop._ What's your meaning "dedicated service app"? What kind of service it will be? How do I'll share resources with it? The background work done on shared objects initialized by the main thread. How do I will seperate them?

Comment: @Roni, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) is what I mean.  You can communicate with it using WCF, i.e. this service app can expose a WCF endpoint.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the clarification. What do you mean  _ This will enable you to have a proper control over the life of your "endless" loop_ How it enables proper control? Which ability/advantage the use of Windows Service suggested?

Comment: @Roni, Windows Services are stateful, meaning you don't fire-and-forget a long-running background task.  You will be able to spawn a thread that lives for the whole life of your Windows Service, which you can initialize and restart if it crashes for some reason.

Comment: @Nick Thanks! Understood. If I'll go your way, Does use of `Task.Run(() => Endlessloop()).ContinueWith(() => HandleEndlessLoppFailure())`  can be a good approach?

Comment: @Roni, for long-running task you might want to create the task using `new Task(() => Endlessloop(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)`.  This creates a dedicated thread for the task.